# Using both regular classes and wsgi applications in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

I want to ask if i write regular class called (zip class) and `class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):`,i want to ask if i can call these two classes from the main as:

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [('/serve', ServeHandler),], debug=True)
    ServeHandler),], debug=True)
    c=zip()
    c.z()
    run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Such that `zip()`is a class and has a member function called `z()`,but the problem is when i ran my code `class zip()` is executed successfully,but the application in the main didn't execute!!Have any ideas for this problem??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to _do_?

Answer (score 1):

Not really enough info to answer your question.  Short answer is yes, you can run regular classes and "wsgi applications" (which are really just a regular python class).

Most likely c.z() is doing something illegal and terminating before run_wsgi_app() is called.

I'll further assume (because you didn't say) that this works fine on your local dev machine (because, if it doesn't, you should be able to debug it on your own), and it doesn't run on GAE.  Given you call it zip(), I'm guessing you might be trying to do some file access, which will work locally, but file accesses are not supported on app engine.